# Time offset value of a datetime is missing in Azure Web API application

Tags: rest, azure, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, azure-api-apps

I have a wep api hosted in Azure which is .NET Core. It is a simple CRUD api for now. I have an interesting problem that I could not find or understand the reason.

In my api, there is a *DateTime* property as usual. When I post a data to api, the time offset disappears in server side.

"dateTime":"2016-08-29T05:13:21.931+03:00" the +03:00 turns into 00:00

Can anyone explain the reason and the solution?

```
{
   "content":"Test Data",
   "location":{
      "name":"Some Location",
      "address":"",
      "latitude":41.0920448,
      "longitude":28.9444847
   },
   "owner":{
      "userName":"Some User",
      "name":null,
      "registrationType":0,
      "profilePictureURL":null
   },
   "dateTime":"2016-08-29T05:13:21.931+03:00",
   "createTime":"2016-08-29T05:13:21.7791051+00:00",
   "rankingPoint":0.0
}
```

Comment: Do you post datetime from client side or your datetime will be directly get from SQL Server or Azure Server ?

Comment: I post from client as above

Comment: Does it convert immediately or do you store that in SQL server then when you retrieve back it convert to 00:00 ?

Comment: Read my previous comment and also If possible please provide me info How did you verified that it converted to 00:00?

Comment: I don't have any SQL or other persistence tier. I have a dictionary and I just add values in it. Just send JSON data as "dateTime":"2016-08-29T05:13:21.931+03:00" from Postman or Fiddler; and my object's datetime value in server side is 2016-08-29T05:13:21.931+00:00. I verified this by checking dictionary items.

Comment: Bacause your azure site running on that timezone. 00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.First of all your azure service is runnig on 00:00 Timezone.

2. if you look at DateTime structure it has special property called Kind. During serialization/deserialization this property take into consideration.

   DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
   // dt.Kind  ( Local , Utc etc).

   The way serialization works it look this property at server side Json Serialziation setting.
   This option is also no help.

**3. Simple and Best Solution I found is to use DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime.**

Comment: Thanks a lot...this is a legit solution for my case.